# Why is this IMPORTXML formula showing an error?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.whatsonglasgow.co.uk/events/this-weekend/", "//*[@id="page-content"]/div[1]/div[5]/div/h4/a")
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you used double quotes `(")` twice in the `xpath_query` which caused a parse error. The following shall work

`=IMPORTXML("http://www.whatsonglasgow.co.uk/events/this-weekend/", "//*[@id='page-content']/div[1]/div[5]/div/h4/a")`

Output: `Good Move Glasgow Health Walks`

> Notice the difference between the original `[@id="page-content"]` with
>   double-quotes `(")`, and the new `[@id='page-content']` with single-quotes `(')`.

This is usually explained under **string literal encapsulation** guidelines. There is no universal rule & it depends on the coding language. A reasonable explanation of C-like languages can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html).